# Use URL parameter to create dynamic content

Tags: urls, parameter

I need to get the following task done:
My client has a huge product database with way over a thousand different products with tons of details. We don't want to generate every product page individually. The idea was to get the parameters from the url, run a query against the db and display the result on a more or less static page.

I'm pretty new to wordpress and there is most likely already an approach for my problem. Any hints?

Greetings Fabian

[image: short explanation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "Page Template". Template hierarchy is a good resource, especially [visual overview](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#visual-overview) shows very clear idea.

In the template, you can use $_GET.

Comment: Hi idpokute!
Thanks for the link - template hierachy helped a lot ... if you don't know where to start, wordpress can be very confusing.
I solved the task with a child template (I don't want to break the updatability of the original template), created a static page template for the specific site and enhanced the functions.php with my logic. Page redirect in htaccess is not nice but works as intended.